# Polarization of Picard variety

Tags: complex-geometry, vector-bundles, picard-scheme

Let $X$ be a complex projective manifold of dimension $m$ with positive closed $(1,1)$ form $\omega$ induced by a projective embedding and let $Pic^0(X)$ be the associated Picard torus. This is a polarized abelian variety with polarization induced by the hermitian form $H$ on $H^0(X,\Omega^1_X)$ given by $$H(\alpha,\beta)=-2i\int_X\omega^{m-1} \wedge \alpha \wedge \bar{\beta}$$

I do not manage to prove that this is positive definite:tried to write $\omega$ explicitly locally using Kahler property but I'm not getting anything. I would not know how to use that $\omega$ comes from the Chern class of  a positive line bundle

Comment: Consider this: $\omega$ corresponds by Poincaré duality to a hyperplane section $H\cdot X$ of $X$ (under the projective embedding), and $\omega^{m-1}$ corresponds to $H^{m-1}\cdot X = C$. Then $H(\alpha,\beta) = -2i\int_C \alpha\wedge\bar\beta$. Then it is now clear that $H(\alpha,\alpha)>0$ unless $\alpha=0$.

Comment: Sorry, how do you prove that the curve $C$ is smooth? Using Bertini?

Comment: Yes, sure, for generic $H^{m-1}$ this will be nonsingular.

Comment: Thank you a lot !